# Updating label and switching scenes JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, label

I've learned JavaFX only from the basic tutorials on YouTube and I've learned to switch scenes like this. But there was nothing about updating labels which I need in my application.

I have a following code:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class GUI extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene setup, results;
    Button next;
    Label statusL2; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        next = new Button("Go to the next scene");
        next.setOnAction(e -> {
                window.setScene(results);
                statusL2 = new Label("GOOD STRING");
        });
        StackPane setupLayout = new StackPane();
        setupLayout.getChildren().addAll(next);
        setup = new Scene(setupLayout, 554, 263);
        statusL2 = new Label("STRING WHICH SHOULDN'T BE SHOWN AT ANY POINT");
        VBox resultsLayout = new VBox();
        resultsLayout.getChildren().addAll(statusL2);
        results = new Scene(resultsLayout, 700, 500);
        window.setScene(setup);
        window.show();

    }
}
```

I would like to have "GOOD STRING" shown at the second scene. Should I put the update of the text (setText()) in a different thread?

If so, how would I be able to call methods of i.e. `statusL2` if it's not static? Which object it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change one line in the action handler to

```
            statusL2.setText("GOOD STRING");
```